# React.js Erro ao tentar acessar dados aninhados de um Json via state do componente

Tags: json, react

Estou iniciando com React.js e estou com problemas para acessar dados aninhados em um JSON.

Estou usando o `whatwg-fetch` para fazer a requisição e está funcionando, porém não consigo acessar os dados aninhados do JSON, exemplo: `data.title` ele exibe na tela normalmente, porém `data.container.title` ele acusa o erro:

> App.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Já procurei em outros lugares inclusive na versão inglês do stackoverflow, artigos em portugues e em inglês e não encontrei uma resposta, alguém pode me ajudar? segue o código e o json acessado.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { dados:[] };
}

loadContentFromServer() {
 const url = this.props.url;

 fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(json => {
     console.log(json);
     this.setState({ dados: json });
   });
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadContentFromServer();
}

render(){
  const data = this.state.dados;
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h1 className="title">
        {data.container.title}<br/>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Passando a url do Json

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(<App url="http://localhost:3232/json/content.json"/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**content.json**

```
{
  "title": "Titulo",
  "numbers": [0, 1, 2, 3],
  "container": {
    "title": "Titulo",
    "content": "conteúdo da página"
  }
}
```

Comment: O React já chama o render antes de você fazer a requisição no `didMount` e receber o resultado. Antes da requisição ocorrer, não existe `data.container.title`, então acho que seja este o problema. Sendo assim, tente iniciar `data.container.title` com alguma outra informação antes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens de ter em conta que ambos o `fetch()` e o `this.setState({ dados: json });` são assíncronos. Isso quer dizer que a primeira vez que o React tentar renderizar esse componente o valor de `this.state.dados` ainda vai ser uma array vazia como setado no construtor da classe do componente.

Então tens de criar uma verificação para o render não acontecer, ou seja renderizar `null`.

Algo assim:

```
render(){
  const data = this.state.dados;
  if (!data.container) return null;
  return (
    <div className="box">
      <h1 className="title">
        {data.container.title}<br/>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

#### Nota:

No construtor inicias o `state` assim: `this.state = { dados:[] };` mas não me parece que é isso que o teu JSON retorna..., o teu JSON parece ser um objeto. Nesse caso seria mais correto setar o `state` assim: `this.state = { dados:{} };`.

Se o JSON for uma array, então o construtor está semanticamente correto mas o código no `render` não está. Aí precisas de aceder ao índice da array que pretendes. Algo assim:

```
{data[0].container.title}<br/>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio, funcionou perfeitamente, porém ainda não entendi porque ele consegue acessar o primeiro nível do JSON como se tivesse carregado os dados parcialmente, e realmente o `this.state = { dados:[] }` estava errado, eu corrigi para `this.state = { dados: {} }`

Comment: @LeandroM.Silva ótimo ter funcionado! Podes explicar melhor _"consegue acessar o primeiro nível do JSON"_? onde achas que isso acontece?

Comment: desculpe a demora para responder, então eu percebi que quando eu acessava `dados.title` na minha aplicação ele retornava o valor correto, porém, quando eu tentava acessar `dados.container.title` ou `dados.container.content` o console acusa error de undefined! tentei replicar o erro pelo jsFiddle pra ficar mais claro mas não consegui!

Comment: @LeandroM.Silva Podes colocar aqui o que aparece na consola com `.then(response => console.log(typeof response, response))`?